# Encrypt symmetric key or message first PGP?

Tags: encryption, pgp, rsa, gnupg, asymmetric

I understand the concept of the hybrid-cryptosystem that OpenPGP uses by generating a random symmetric key, using that to encrypt the message before encrypting itself with the recipient's public key.

However, in this paper describing OpenPGP, it describes the process the other way: encrypting the symmetric key, before using that encrypted key to encrypt the message. Is this correct?

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The step explained in the paper is correct. The confusion you probably are facing is with the key exchange step I guess.

Let me explain it further.

Let A be the sender and B, the recipient.

- A generates the message - **M**
- A generates a pseudorandom session key - **K** `Key for symmetric encryption`
- A encrypts the message M with  session key K - **E(K,M)** `Message encrypted with symmetric encryption`
- A encrypts the session key K with public key of B - **E(KBPUB, K)** `K encrypted with public key of B so that B can retrieve K with it's private key.`
- A appends the results of step 3 and 4 and sends it to B -  **E(K,M) || E(KBPUB, K)**
- B receives **E(K,M) || E(KBPUB, K)**
- B retrieves K from E(KBPUB, K) -> **K = E[KBPRIV, E(KBPUB, K)]** `Retrieving K by decrypting it with private key of B.`
- B uses K to retrieve M from E(K,M) -> **M = D[K, E(K,M)]** `Decrypting the symmetrically encrypted message.`

Your confusion is in the 3rd and 4th steps. Te order of 3rd and 4th steps doesn't matter as you see from the above.

Comment: I think the confusion was from me thinking that it was using the encrypted symmetric key to encrypt the message, but instead they both use the original session key instead